# Add new xml nodes dynamically with N number of nested tags

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing, xmlslurper, xml-builder

I have the below sample xml.

```
<A>
  <B>Test@yopmail.com</B>           
</A>
```

And I want to insert a new set of xml message tags dynamically using groovy as the below 2 samples. For example every message will have the A,B & C tags. But the nested tags in C tag will be generated dynamically( both name and value of the tag).

Sample 1

```
<A>
    <B>Test@yopmail.com</B>
    <C>
      <Info name="Name">Jane</Info>
      <Info name="Age">1</Info>
    </C
    <C>
      <Info name="Name">Kate</Info>
      <Info name="Age">100</Info>
    </C>
</A>
```

Sample 2

```
<A>
    <B>Test@yopmail.com</B>
    <C>
      <Info name="Name">Hello</Info>
      <Info name="Age">100</Info>
      <Info name="Country">Test</Country>
    </C
    <C>
      <Info name="Name">Hello world</Info>
      <Info name="Age">200</Info>
      <Info name="Country">USA</Country>
    </C
</A>
```

I tried to achieve it by using appendNode to construct the tags dynamically and insert it under C tag. But couldn't find a way to map the nested tags under C tag dynamically. Because at times it can be 1 parameter or 100 parameters under the C tag with name and values.

```
def root = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parseText(xmlAsString)
        root.appendNode {
            C{
//How to dynamically insert the Parameters if we get to know the parameter list(name and value) at runtime
                Info(Name: 'Name','Hello')
                Info(Name:'Age','100')
                Info(Name:'Country','Test')
            }
        }
        XmlUtil.serialize(root)
```

Comment: Do you mean `Info( name: 'Name', 'Hello world' )...`?  You had tag named `Info`, but in your code you wrote `Parameter`.  It was confusing.

Comment: Hi @chubbsondubs thank you for pointing it, now its updated.

Answer (score 1):

I think if I understand what you mean it'd be something like this:

```
List<Parameter> parameters = [...]
def root = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parseText(xmlAsString)
root.appendNode {
   C {
     parameters.each { param ->
        Info( name: param.name, param.value )
     }
   }
}
XmlUtil.serialize(root)
```